# How to standardise/normalise csv data in a tensorflow 2 dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, batch-normalization

Does anyone know how to apply standardisation (or normalisation) on the numerical features of a dataset loaded in batch via `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` in TF 2?

The tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv has the funny remark "The mean based normalization used here requires knowing the means of each column ahead of time" which is of course rubbish. The whole point of loading a CSV using the `make_csv_dataset` method is because you don't want to load it in full, because it is too large for memory (10 GB in my case).

I've looked at keras batch normalisation, as a layer in the model, but I'm building an anomaly detection model which is symmetrical, so I can't denormalise my data at the end to see how good the output values match the input values.

In my pandas dataframe test code (with a smaller CSV), where I load the entire dataset in memory, I can easily use `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`, but not with the datasets that are loaded in batch when the model is training.

I would be happy with a normaliser that works on the batches of my dataset, where I accept it is not fully correct, but close.

Is there a way? TIA